# Using Left join sql query

Tags: vb.net, left-join

I'm trying to retrieve DBName, DBNo, DBAmount, DBCountedAmount from Table A and include NewFormNo from Table B so I did this

Table A

```
|DBName |DBNo    | DBAmount | DBCountedAmount     |
|-------|--------|----------|---------------------|
|Derek  |503456  | 2000     |     2000            |
|John   |554422  | 40000    |     4000            |
```

Table B

```
|DBName |DBNo    | DBAmount | DBCountedAmount     | FormNo|
|-------|--------|----------|---------------------|-------|
|Derek  |503456  | 2000     |     2000            |00001  |
|John   |554422  | 40000    |     4000            |00002  |
```

So I did this , but it doesnt return the row I want

```
SELECT A.DBName,A.DBNo,A.DBAmount,A.DBCountedAmount,B.FormNo FROM Table A LEFT JOIN Table B ON A.DBNo=B.DBNo AND A.DBNo= '503456'
```

I want to retrieve this

```
|DBName |DBNo    | DBAmount | DBCountedAmount     | FormNo|
|-------|--------|----------|---------------------|-------|
|Derek  |503456  | 2000     |     2000            |00001  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
AND A.DBNo= '503456'
```

to this

```
WHERE A.DBNo= '503456'
```

Also, what is the type of `DBNo`? If it's numeric, you can remove the ''

Comment: @DerekToh what are the exact names of your tables? Also, what are the column data types? Also, I have to ask, since Table B is exactly the same as Table A with the exception of the FormNo column, why not just select from Table B?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT A.DBName, A.DBNo, A.DBAmount, A.DBCountedAmount 
FROM Table A 
LEFT JOIN Table B ON A.DBNo=B.DBNo
WHERE A.DBNo= '503456'
```

Comment: do you get any results if you removed the WHERE statement ?

Comment: I managed to find out what the problem was , I can retrieve the row now but the retrieved row shows my NewFormNo as NULL

Answer (score 0):

As per your question there is no need of left outer join. You can directly get by using inner join like this:

```
SELECT distinct a.DBname, a.DBno, a.Dbamount, a.Dbamountcount, b.FormNo 
FROM tableA a inner join tableB b 
on a.DBno = b.DBno 
and a.DBno = 503456
```